# Prove that Carmichael number has no primitive roots

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Prove that if $n$ is a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), then $n$ has no primitive roots. This seems tricky to prove, and the only logical explanation for this is that it contradicts the basis of the [Lucas Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test), but again that is not proving the original statement.

Comment: I don't see anything of this sort in the page you linked.  Note that the discussion on that page is talking about units mod $n$ which have order $n-1$, which is much stronger than just being a primitive root (it implies $n$ is prime).

Answer (score 2):

This is not tricky to prove, because a Carmichael number is a square-free number with at least three (different) prime factors, so it obviously does not have the form which admits primitive roots: $2, 4, p^k, 2p^k$ with an odd prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this quite quickly using the classification of numbers with primitive roots: $n$ has a primitive root iff $n$ is $2$, $4$, or of the form $p^k$ or $2p^k$ for $p$ an odd prime.  So you just have to check that these are not Carmichael.  This is easy: any Carmichael number is odd, so you only have to check the case $n=p^k$.  In that case, if $a$ is a primitive root, $a^n=a$ mod $n$ implies $n-1=p^k-1$ is divisible by $\phi(n)=(p-1)p^{k-1}$, which is impossible for $k>1$.